# Azure DevOps - Group permission over a repository and builds related to that repository

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How do I know what actions a particular group can perform over a particular repository? or a particular pipeline?

I am using the DevOps API to get a list of all the Groups, Repositories, and Builds. But I don't know how to combine them together to get the actions that a Group can perform over that repository?

Is there an API that would help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

I attempted and tested with the related [Azure DevOps REST API for Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1), and it seems that there is not any available API can get the detailed permissions of a particular group on the particular repository or pipeline.

**[UPDATE]**

Maybe, you can try the following steps to see if you can find an available API for use:

1. Navigate to the Security page of a particular repository or pipeline.
2. Press **F12** to open the **Developer Tools** of the browser and select **Network** tab. And Clean all existing logs.
3. On the Security page, click on a particular group to show the permissions of it.
4. From the logs on the **Network** tab, you can see some API requests are listed.
5. From the listed API requests, you should be able to find the related API.

Comment: So I was able to figure out what the permissions of a group have over a repository, so basically, we need to call the ACL API with the security namespace ID, Token for the resource (repoV2/project Id/Repo Id) along with the Group Descriptor. Which returned a Allow and a Deny Bitmask, which is exactly what I needed

Comment: Hi @AashutoshMallik, Yes, that's correct.